# alter table if model changes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

is there any way in EF not to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, only insert new colomns and delete unused properties?
How to manage it when i'm using POCO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Code First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx), included in Entity Framework 4.3.

**Update**

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, the closest I can think of to automating the process is [automatic migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I saw it. But it's a hand way to manage each property. Is there any automation like in linq to sql classes?

Comment: @Evg Not sure I understand what you mean. Updated my answer with a ref to Automatic migrations, but not sure if that is what you are looking for. Otherwise, please try to elaborate a bit more on your needs.

Comment: @Evg - Christofer is right, that's the best you can get it does 'incremental updates' etc.